# Different coefficients for L1-L2 regularisation

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, regularized

I'd like to regularise the weights of a network with both L1 and L2 regularisation. However, I can't find a way to vary the strength of the regularisations independently. The Keras [documentation](https://keras.io/regularizers/) doesn't provide any information either.

So, **is there a way to use different strengths in the `l1_l2` regulariser?** Or perhaps an alternative method to achieve the same result?

My current model is simply:

```
stren = 0.001
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(64, input_dim=148, activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=reg.l2(stren)))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid', kernel_regularizer=reg.l2(stren)))
```

And I'd like to be able to have something along the lines of:

```
kernel_regularizer=reg.l1_l2(l1_str, l2_str)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Of course you can vary the strengths of [regularizers](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/regularizers.py) independently:

```py
from keras import regularizers

regularizers.l1_l2(l1=0.001, l2=0.1) # the strength of l1 is set to 0.001 and l2 to 0.1
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It's odd they didn't add a mention of that into the documentation..

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could try to customize the regularization according to your loss function and design a user-defined regularization function in the Keras framework. Something like this:

```
def l1_l2(l1=0.01, l2=0.01):
    return L1L2(l1=l1, l2=l2)
```

Or use the dropout function between layers such as `Dropout(0.2)`.